# Issue in thread pool using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

we are having issues when accessing to application , the application is completely down, We are using SPring boot and has below Jars in lib folder. We are getting connection issues to pool and application is not accessible.

In tomcat tool box xml file we have

```
<poolAttribute>
                                    <Name>factory</Name>
                                     <Value>org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory</Value>
                                  </poolAttribute>
```

[image]